# Problem Using ALB as a target for NLB with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer, nlb

I am trying to use an ALB as the target for NLB, it gets created fine without a problem. but when I do terraform destroy I get this error **"error deleting Listener  ResourceInUse: Listener port '80' is in use by registered target and cannot be removed."** I tried a lot of different ideas and nothing is working. But if I comment/remove the section of the NLB and keep the ALB code only, I can create and destroy without problems. any ideas?
this is my code

```
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = "alb"
  internal = true
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.allow_web.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.private-01.id, aws_subnet.private-02.id]

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "alb-tg-http" {
  name     = "${random_string.alb_prefix.result}-alb-tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.provider.id
   health_check {
      path                = "/"
      protocol            = "HTTP"
      matcher             = "200"
      interval            = 15
      timeout             = 3
      healthy_threshold   = 2
      unhealthy_threshold = 2
    }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb-tg-http.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "alb-tg-attachment" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb-tg-http.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.web.id
  port             = aws_lb_listener.alb-listener.port
}

resource "aws_lb" "nlb" {
  name               = "test-lb-tf"
  internal           = true
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.private-01.id, aws_subnet.private-02.id]

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nlb-tg" {
  name        = "nlb-tg"
  target_type = "alb"
  port        = 80
  protocol    = "TCP"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.provider.id
}


resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nlb-attachment" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nlb-tg.arn
  target_id        = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port             = aws_lb_listener.nlb_listener.port
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "nlb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.nlb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "TCP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nlb-tg.arn
  }
}

# Generate a random string to add it to the name of the Target Group
resource "random_string" "alb_prefix" {
  length  = 4
  upper   = false
  special = false
}
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you get "Listener port '80' is in use by registered target and cannot be removed."?

Comment: Still not able to get it to create and destroy without errors. whatever creates it without error will destroy it with error and vice versa. this is a link for the creation error https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/21558. i am using the latest AWS provider version and latest terraform as well

Comment: when I get a creation error then I deploy again on top of the first deploy it goes through. the same behavior with the destroy command. when I get the error then run the destroy for the second time, and it goes throug.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't have two listeners on the same port**. Your `aws_lb_listener.nlb_listener` and `aws_lb_listener.alb-listener` are at port `80` which results in the error.

You have to use different port for one of these listeners, e.g. `8080`.

Comment: that is what i get when i change the port of one of the listener
Error registering targets with target group: ValidationError: If the target type is ALB, the target must have at least one listener that matches the target group port or any specified port overrides. i think this error is kind of a bug, because it doesn't make sense. i have the ALB listener matching the target group port of the nlb.

Comment: @engzaz Sadly I don't know what is your current version of the program. My answer addresses the issue that you reported in the question . It would be better to make new question, with new code for the new error that you get. Also if my answer was to solve the error you originally reported, it's acceptance would be appreciated.